# DrawPath Points with rounded edges

Tags: c#, graphics, draw

I'm drawing a GraphicPant with lines that are intersecting and I'm wondering if the edges of the lines could be rounded.

The code with that I draw is:

```
Graphics G = e.Graphics;
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
gp.AddLine((float)(line.startX), (float)(line.startY), (float)(line.endX), (float)(line.endY));
gp.CloseFigure();

using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkGray, 0.0001f))
   {
    G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    G.Clear(Color.White);
    G.DrawPath(pen, gp)
   }
```

If it could look like this:
[image]

Comment: Here, I googled this up for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bdt6zkb.aspx

Comment: Oh wow, searched for 30 mins and nothing similair.. But when I define start and end caps as `LineCap.Round`, but the line still has square edges. Penthickness is `0.001f`, does that matter?

Comment: Looks like it only works with DrawLine, not DrawPath. You might have to draw the path line-by-line.

Comment: It works just fine with DrawPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using such a tiny `Pen.Width` will result in a line that is only **one** pixel 'thick'. But **pixels are always square** by definition. So if you enlarge with a non-dithering or -antialising software it will **look** as if the ends were square.

But they really have **no shape** at all as they do not have a *real* size. Instead their width is a *virtual* number: The one pixel that is used is simply the **default** minimum used so the line doesn't **disappear**.

So: Yes the `Pen.Width` does matter.

So: Do set it to a reasonable number greater than 1 and you will see the round endpoints..

You could also scale the `Graphics` object by a suitable number and you would see the rounded ends as well..If you want to try that, don't forget to adapt the coodinates to the extreme scaling!

---

For several lines created by `AddLines` (or `AddPolygon` if you were serious about the `CloseFigure`) also set the `LineJoin`:

```
pen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
```

Comment: Yep the `pen.Linejoin` did the trick, the end caps aren't making any difference. If you remember from my previous questions, the whole coordinate system was scaled up, so the pen width is actually a thick line considering the scaling. My apologies for not adding more background code with the question, didn't think it would matter.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
```

Comment: when I define start and end caps as `LineCap.Round`, but the line still has square edges. My pen thickness is `0.001f`, does that matter?

Comment: Actually it probably should __also__ be `pen.LineJoin = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineJoin.Round` - And what are his units for a `Pen.Width = 0.001f` ?? not pixels I presume?!?! And what does a   `gp.CloseFigure();` do with only one line???